# Android runtime permissions process: Can I send extras with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions?

Tags: android-permissions, runtime-permissions, android-bundle, dangerous-permissions

Are there any methods to send bundle/extras (like what we do with intents) during a request for granting dangerous permissions of android?

In normal process for granting dangerous permissions for android, we should call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)` which is defined as below according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)):

```
void requestPermissions (Activity activity, String[] permissions,int requestCode)
```

As it can be seen there is no options for sending any extra information in permission request. Currently I use static parameters inside my activity to restore them after my permission will be granted.

I want to know are there any options for this?

Answer (score 1):

I include intents this way first part of code just checks to see if we have a SD CARD or not

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //.... write file into storage ...
            System.out.println("SDK > BuildVersion TRUE");
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 666);  // Comment 26
            System.out.println("go to requestPermissions");
        }
    }
    onLoad();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 666: // Allowed was selected so Permission granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Permission Granted",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = s.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextSize(18);
                textView.setMaxLines(6);
                s.show();

                // do your work here

            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                // User selected the Never Ask Again Option Change settings in app settings manually
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Change Permissions in Settings");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click SETTINGS to Manually Set\n\n"+"Permissions to use Database Storage")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);     // Comment 3.
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            } else {
                    // User selected Deny Dialog to EXIT App ==> OR <== RETRY to have a second chance to Allow Permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Second Chance");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click RETRY to Set Permissions to Allow\n\n"+"Click EXIT to the Close App")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Integer.parseInt(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    finish();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }};
```